# How to add a timeout to Runtime.exec() but checking exit value?

Tags: java, process, timeout, runtime, exec

As you know, you can add a timeout to a exec() using this:

```
Process p = ...
if(!p.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
    //timeout - kill the process. 
    p.destroyForcibly();
}
```

The problem is that using that code snippet you can't know the result value of the process, and I need to know it because i need to know if the exit value is 0 (success) or different of 0 (error).

Is there a way to achieve this?

If you use the old method, you can, but is not compatible with a timeout:

```
exit = process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `p.exitValue()` to get hold of the exit value, but note that you will get an `IllegalThreadStateException` if the subprocess represented by this Process object has not yet terminated so don't use this method if the `waitFor()` times out.

```
Process p = ...
if(!p.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
    //timeout - kill the process. 
    p.destroyForcibly();
} else {
    int exitValue = p.exitValue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: that whould return the exit value only if the timeout has been launched, i need to know the exit value if the timeout has not been launched

Comment: can i safely put exitvalue after the if? will not launch a illegalthreadstateexception?